# Dial into FTP server (Data logger) using python (OS independent)

Tags: python, ftp, modem, dial-up

I have a few data loggers in the field. The manufacturer set them up as dial up ftp servers. I'm writing a python program that automagically downloads all the latest files from the server into a specified folder on my computer.

1. Which OS independent library do you recommend for dial up?
2. Do you have any suggestions, comments, or concerns that you can share?

Thanks

Comment: does the manufacturer not providing you with the relevant software?

Comment: @SilentGhost - Well I use cuteftp to download the data now, but manually dialing up into 10 sites and downloading data sets, is a waste of time really. I was looking to automate the process when the computer is idling or after hours

Comment: What we use is built-in scheduler from the manufacturer software, that is fairly flexible and allows also for various hook scripts to be executed upon downloading. No manual work is required whatsoever.

Comment: All the manufacturer has given us is the software to analyze the data. We had to setup the ftp manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Python's built-in [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)? Looks pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something?

For using a modem with Python, [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t353542-addressing-the-modem-via-pyserial.html) talks about using the [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module.

I've never used pyserial with a modem, but I have with a USB port and an arduino. It was pretty straight forward, so I'm sure with some research about modem communication you could do it pretty easily. PySerial doesn't come with python by default, but from their site,

> [PySerial] provides backends for Python running on Windows, Linux, BSD (possibly any POSIX compliant system), Jython and IronPython (.NET and Mono).

and [earlier versions](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html#older-versions) exist for MacOS and others.